# Python Pandas Time Series Manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, resampling

I have a pandas dataframe with the following structure:

```
                     Date     Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
0     2003-10-01 00:00:00  1.16500  1.16700  1.16400  1.16690    1125
1     2003-10-01 01:00:00  1.16680  1.16790  1.16600  1.16720     933
............
```

Those are continuos time values because it is Eur/Usd data.
I want to resample this creating a daily dataframe that uses as Open value the value on Open column for Date XXXX-XX-XX 09:00:00 and for Close value the Close column value for XXXX-XX-XX 16:00:00. High and low should be the higher high and the lower Low between XXXX-XX-XX 09:00:00 and XXXX-XX-XX 16:00:00.
Volume should be the sum of volumes between XXXX-XX-XX 09:00:00 and XXXX-XX-XX 16:00:00.
Is there an easy way to do that in pandas? 
How to?

Thanks

Comment: You have to rephrase your question.

Comment: I have a 24 Hour financial time series OHLC and volume data with 1 hour timeframe, I Want to resample it to daily timeframe but using only data between 09:00:00 and 17:00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Only times between 09:00:00 and 16:00:00.**

`between_time` is a nice simple way to get the times you need

```
ts = ts.between_time('9:00','16:00')
```

**Resample** using recommended syntax:

and to avoid the 'future warning' with your implementation of `resample` try this:

```
ohlc_dict = {                                                                                                             
'Open':'first',                                                                                                    
'High':'max',                                                                                                       
'Low':'min',                                                                                                        
'Close': 'last',                                                                                                    
'Volume': 'sum'  }

dailyData = ts.resample('1d').agg(ohlc_dict)
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `between_time`. TIL.

Answer (score 1):

This is a two-step process. First you need to drop data that's outside of your daily hourly bounds; then you need to resample that to daily frequency.

Suppose this our timeseries:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ts = pd.Series(np.random.random(72), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H'))
```

To filter by hour, we can create a boolean array asking each timestamp in our data whether or not its hours is within our hours of interest, then use that to index our timeseries:

```
ts_filtered = ts[ts.index.map(lambda time: 9 <= time.hour <= 17)]
```

Then, to resample, just use `resample`:

```
daily_stats = ts_filtered.resample('D').mean()
```

Which gets us:

```
2011-01-01    0.507943
2011-01-02    0.416317
2011-01-03    0.573760
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanx, this is great, just I miss one part, for the Open resempled column I need to use the 09:00:00 Open value, while for the Close column I need to use the 17:00:00 Close value. For High column I need to use the highest value in the 09:00:00-17:00:00 range. Is there a way to do that? Thanks

Comment: Yes. Instead of ending that last statement with `mean()`, use `agg()`, passing it a dictionary where the keys are each variable name and the values are functions for what you want to do to them. In your case it sounds like you need `ts_filtered.resample('D').agg({'High': max, 'Open': lambda vals: vals.values[0], 'Close': lambda vals: vals.values[-1]})`.

Comment: this last passage throws me the following error:                                                                                              IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: That means that one of the groups is empty. Not sure but I don't think you should be getting that...try `lambda vals: vals.values[-1] if len(vals) else float('NaN')`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I also found this solution:

> ```
> ohlc_dict = {                                                                                                             
> 'Open':'first',                                                                                                    
> 'High':'max',                                                                                                       
> 'Low':'min',                                                                                                        
> 'Close': 'last',                                                                                                    
> 'Volume': 'sum'  }
>
> df_filtered_daily = df_filtered.resample('D', how=ohlc_dict, closed='left', label='left')
> ```